# Internet Explorer 10 "This page cannot be displayed" When loading my site

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, web, https, internet-explorer-10

Here is what's happening:

A website I'm managing is only working in IE11, Chrome and Firefox. I need to make it work on IE10, but on IE10 it gives me "This page cannot be displayed"

**What I tried so far:**

- Made tests on Browserstack.com, confirmed that the issue is related to HTTPS or SSL/TSL. When I try on HTTPS the site doesn't load, when I try it on HTTP it does. (However I will need HTTPS because there are registration forms and whatnot).
- I've searched a lot to see if anyone was having similar issues with IE10, it was very difficult to find anything about this.
- I had a code that redirects users from HTTP to HTTPS, it's the reason why it wasn't working on IE10 when I was loading it with normal HTTP, it loads in normal HTTP after removing this code, however the HTTPS issue remains.
- Because all my css files were linked by HTTPS, the site does not load the CSS files on HTTP, this particular issue I can fix by myself, but I thought it might be useful to know.

**Details that could help you help me**

- This web system is created with PHP, in an MVC framework.
- Our SSL/TLS certificate was issued by COMODO CA Limited
- Our server does not have a dedicated IP address, so browsers that don't support SNI supposedly give false security warnings, however IE10 does support SNI
- This is the code I have (And took out) for redirecting users from HTTP to HTTPS

  `if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on" && ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "website.net" || $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "www.website.net") )
  {
      header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
      exit();
  }`
- When still trying to access it from HTTPS, IE10 suggests that I make sure SSL and TLS protocols are enabled, if this fixes the issue it would be great but I doubt all the users that will access the website will know how to do this, ideally I'd like it to work without having to do this workaround.
- I have a user that tried accessing the website with Chrome, using WebSense, and it denied access to the website with this message: "VERIFY DENY: Peer disconnected after first handshake message: Possibly SSL/TLS Protocol level is too low or unsupported on the server".

If there's any other information you need to help me figure this out just ask, thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the source of the problem, after running some tests on ssllabs I discovered my server only supports TLS versions 1.1 and 1.2, while IE10 by default has only TLS 1.0 enabled, TLS 1.0 is deemed a no longer safe protocol, it has known cryptographic weaknesses that can lead to the compromise of sensitive data within an encrypted session. 
In order to remain PCI compliant we had to disable the support of TLS 1.0 only for web, but keep it for emails. IE10 does support TLS versions 1.1 and 1.2, but only has 1.0 enabled by default, the users accessing my website by https do not have administrative privileges to upgrade or change these settings, they would need their IT guy to upgrade their browser or change these security settings.

That being said, this issue was not really fixed, but I did find the cause of the problem. There is just nothing more to do about it, I cannot re-enable TLS 1.0 on my server because it is unsafe, so IE10 users just need to upgrade, let this be known for anyone trying to run a website with SSL, if you have TLS 1.0 supported on your server, then it is not PCI compliant and it's unsafe, however if you don't, all IE10 users with no administrative privileges (office environment) will not be able to access your site by https. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested PayPal, eBay, Costco, Overstock, Newegg, Walmart, and Amazon and they all still use TLS 1.0. That may change by the June 30, 2016 deadline. But for now I think it is safe to assume that they are still PCI compliant.